# Assign return value from upper_bound to reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdmap

I find a certain point in an `std::map<int, X>` via upper_bound and then from this point on I iterate backwards. My code looks something like:

```
MAP::reverse_iterator iter;

iter = _map.upper_bound(value);  // Does not compile because upper_bound is not reverse_iterator

while(iter != rbegin()){
    // logic
    --iter;
}
```

I get a compile error because upper_bound() does not return a reverse_iterator.

What is the best approach to remedy this?

Comment: Convert the iterator to a reverse iterator?

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks didnt realise that was possible. If you put it as an answer i'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your iterator to a reverse iterator:

```
auto iter = _map.upper_bound(value);
for (std::reverse_iterator<decltype(iter)> rit{iter}; rit != _map.rend(); ++rit) {
     // Do whatever you want...
}
```

Note that you have to stop when reaching `_map.rend()`, not `_map.rbegin()`, and you need to increment the reverse iterator, not decrement it.

Comment: Is this C++14 or C++11? I'm getting compiler errors on GCC4.8.2 saying it cannot convert std::reverse_iterator<decltype(iter)> rit{map.upper_bound(10)};

Comment: @user997112 This should work in c++11.